# Conditional statement depending on a bound value in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Consider the following markup:

```
<div id="{{Id}}" class="SignAuditItem">
    <h4 class="signDashboardPadding display-inline">{{SignerName}}</h4>
    <%= Resources.General.rep_as %>
    <h5 class="display-inline" id="SignerTypeID"><% %>{{SignerType}}</h5>
    <br />
    <p class="signDashboardPadding display-inline margin-top-0">{{SignerEmail}}</p>

    <h5 class="signDashboardPadding">
    <<<<<<HERE>>>>> if(signerType= someValueStr) <%= Resources.Signing.rep_signing %> else <%= Resources.Signing.rep_SomeOtherMessage %>
    </h5>
</div>
```

I would like to work in the `<<<<here>>>` part.

A different message would be displayed depending on the value of SignerType.

For example, if for this specific signer , the type is "Signer in person", change the message in the h5 tag.

[Visual Representation of what I would like :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUuVk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself by doing :

*

```
<h5 class="signDashboardPadding">{% 
           var signerType = SignerType;
            if(signerType == 'Carbon Copy'){ %}
            <span><%= Resources.Signing.rep_session_cc_routing_later %></span>
        {% } 
        else{ %}
        <span><%= Resources.Signing.rep_session_routing_later %></span>
        {% }
        %}
    </h5>
```

- 